# Replacing values after every nth byte

Tags: hex

Is there any way to replace hex values at specific intervals all at once, whether it be in a hex editor or other program?

For example, if I wanted to replace 4 bytes with "FF FF FF FF" after every 24 bytes.

Before:

```
B8 C7 D8 FF C0 EB 18 A3 C0 85 A0 03 C4 85 00 00 
44 15 B1 B3 42 04 0D 37 3E 6C 93 E4 BB 95 3E 88 
3F 79 12 49 AA B8 C7 00 C0 F9 FF FE C0 85 A0 03 
C4 85 00 00 44 05 11 B3 41 F6 AF CE 3E 7F 3E 6A 
BD 1F 9E C3 3F 77 B8 08 B1 BF CE 00 C0 F9 FF FE 
C0 6A 00 06 C4 7A D3 AF 44 05 11 B3 41 2F 12 FD 
3E BA A6 7C BD 17 F2 D1 3F 6E 31 94 BE CE DF FF
C0 EA D3 AD C0 6A 00 06 C4 68 BF FF 44 1E 16 54 
41 2E 7D E1 BE 23 8D CD BE B9 E1 89 3F 6B 00 A7
```

After:

```
B8 C7 D8 FF C0 EB 18 A3 C0 85 A0 03 C4 85 00 00 
44 15 B1 B3 42 04 0D 37 3E 6C 93 E4 BB 95 3E 88 
3F 79 12 49 FF FF FF FF C0 F9 FF FE C0 85 A0 03 
C4 85 00 00 44 05 11 B3 41 F6 AF CE 3E 7F 3E 6A 
BD 1F 9E C3 3F 77 B8 08 FF FF FF FF C0 F9 FF FE 
C0 6A 00 06 C4 7A D3 AF 44 05 11 B3 41 2F 12 FD 
3E BA A6 7C BD 17 F2 D1 3F 6E 31 94 FF FF FF FF
C0 EA D3 AD C0 6A 00 06 C4 68 BF FF 44 1E 16 54 
41 2E 7D E1 BE 23 8D CD BE B9 E1 89 3F 6B 00 A7
```

Comment: In what context? What tool?

Comment: I guess preferably in a hex editor like HxD, but I don't mind suggestions for doing this through other methods or programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this can be done in 010 Editor using the Hex Operations toolbar.

[image]